# PostgreSQL RLS is not applied as intended

Tags: postgresql, row-level-security

I have a function a function `current_user_selected_upr` that returns a `text`. I want to use this function to apply a rls policy :

```sql
create or replace function current_user_selected_upr() returns text stable language sql as $$
   select 'IDF' as upr;
$$;

create table if not exists doe(
    id serial not null,
    upr text not null default 'NE'
);

create user super_admin nologin;

grant select on doe to super_admin;

create policy doe_admin_policy 
  on public.doe 
  for select to "super_admin"
  using (upr = private.current_user_selected_upr());
```

However, the policy is never applied :

```sql
create or replace function test_rls() returns text language plpgsql security invoker as $$
    declare
        upr_doe text;
        upr_config text;
    begin
        set local role super_admin;
        select current_user_selected_upr() into upr_config;
        select d.upr into upr_doe from doe d;
        return concat('Config : ', upr_config, ' | rls results : ', upr_doe);
    end;                                                                    
$$;
select test_rls();
-- Returns Config : IDF | rls results : NE
```

I have reproduced the problem in a fiddle. The function `current_user_selected_upr` returns `IDF` but the row selected is `NE`. Why ?

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/r1Mrh9QenB6YEuNCAkcqkQ/2

Comment: Your code does not enable RLS for the created table. And you also need to use the `FORCE` option as by default the owner of a table bypasses RLS.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name But I used `set local role` so the selected role should be different from the table owner right ?

Comment: Please don't link only to the code, add the code to the question.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe It's done

Answer (score 1):

I simply forgot to add :

```sql
alter table doe enable row level security;
```